# error in script for number of occurences count

Tags: shell-script

I have written a small script to count number of occurrences of logs in megabyte from a particular file following is my code

```
#!/bin/sh

count=1



while read line
do

        found=$( grep M $line )
        if [ "$found" ]; then

        echo $count")" $line >> filesave.txt
        fi
        count=$((count+1))


done < log1.txt
```

but I am getting error like
 ./count.sh
./count.sh: syntax error at line 10: `found=$' unexpected

Comment: @don_crissti not possible duplicate, it's an exact duplicate.

Comment: `grep M log1.txt | cat -n | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*// ; s/^\([0-9]\+\)[[:space:]]*/\1\)/' >>filesave.txt` and stop asking the same question repeatedly.  the `sed` script is optional if you're happy with the output of `cat -n`.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep M log1.txt | 
    cat -n | 
    sed 's/^[[:space:]]*\([0-9]\+\)[[:space:]]*/\1\)/' >> filesave.txt
```

The `sed` script is optional if you're happy with the output of `cat -n`

```
grep M log1.txt | cat -n >> filesave.txt
```